# JavaScript: counting strings that begin with 'A' within an array - why is my code not counting them all?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to code a loop which counts the amount of strings within the variable 'animals' that begin with an 'A'. There are 8, but the console only logs 7 and I'm not sure why.

```js
const animals = ['Alligator', 'Fox', 'Armadillo', 'Tiger', 'Anteater', 'Raccoon', 'Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Dog', 'Antelope', 'Albatross', 'Cat', 'Alpaca', 'Ape', 'Anaconda'];
  let countAnimals = 0;

  
  for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    const currentAnimal = animals[i]
    if (currentAnimal.indexOf('A')) {
        countAnimals += 1
    }
  }
  
  console.log(countAnimals)
```

Comment: For a more modern approach: `currentAnimal.startsWith("A")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is actually counting the words that **don't** start  with "A". This is because when you have a word that does start with "A", `indexOf("A")` will return `0` and it causes your `if` condition to look like this:

```
if(0)
```

Since `0` is ["falsey"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and therefore implicilty converts to the Boolean `false`, it turns out that words that start with "A" actually cause your `if` condition to evaluate as if it was written like this:

```
if(false)
```

And since `false` is never `true`, you don't enter the `true` branch with words that start with "A", however with any other word that doesn't start with "A", you will get a non-zero number back and non-zero numbers are ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and convert to the Boolean `true` when implicitly converted, so you wind up entering the `true` branch of the `if` statement when words that DON'T start with "A" are encountered.

We can see this by adding a little logging:

```js
const animals = ['Alligator', 'Fox', 'Armadillo', 'Tiger', 'Anteater', 'Raccoon', 'Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Dog', 'Antelope', 'Albatross', 'Cat', 'Alpaca', 'Ape', 'Anaconda'];
  let countAnimals = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    const currentAnimal = animals[i]
    if (currentAnimal.indexOf('A')) {
        // The following will show that your test is actually testing
        // for words that DON'T start with "A" (indexOf returns -1)
        console.log(currentAnimal, currentAnimal.indexOf('A'));
        countAnimals += 1
    }
  }
  
  console.log(countAnimals)
```

You need to check the returned [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to see if it is 0.

```js
const animals = ['Alligator', 'Fox', 'Armadillo', 'Tiger', 'Anteater', 'Raccoon', 'Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Dog', 'Antelope', 'Albatross', 'Cat', 'Alpaca', 'Ape', 'Anaconda'];
  let countAnimals = 0;
 
  for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    const currentAnimal = animals[i]
    if (currentAnimal.indexOf('A') === 0) {
        // By specifying that you need the index to be 0,
        // you get the correct words:
        console.log(currentAnimal, currentAnimal.indexOf('A'));
        countAnimals += 1
    }
  }
  
  console.log(countAnimals)
```

You can also accomplish this using one of the Array.prototype methods, which are  geared  towards these kinds of operations:

```js
const animals = ['Alligator', 'Fox', 'Armadillo', 'Tiger', 'Anteater', 'Raccoon', 'Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Dog', 'Antelope', 'Albatross', 'Cat', 'Alpaca', 'Ape', 'Anaconda'];

// Return a filtered array that only include words that start with "A" and get the length of tthat array.
console.log((animals.filter(word => word.indexOf("A") === 0)).length);
```

Comment: Why would the original code succeed on the first 7, but fail on the last one?  Because Javascript?

Comment: The original code is counting animals that don't start with `A`, of which there are 7: Fox, Tiger, Raccoon, Chicken, Sheep, Dog, Cat. For these, `indexOf('A')` returns `-1`, which is truthy. For the other animals that do start with `A`, `indexOf('A')` returns `0`, which is falsey.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See updated answer for clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are counting indices of `-1` or other values from `1` or greater.

[`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` for not found or the index of the found substring.

To overcome this, you need to check with zero

```
animals[i].indexOf('A') === 0
```

or check the value at index directly

```
animals[i][0] === 'A'
```

or with [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```
animals[i].startsWith('A')
```

```js
const animals = ['Alligator', 'Fox', 'Armadillo', 'Tiger', 'Anteater', 'Raccoon', 'Chicken', 'Sheep', 'Dog', 'Antelope', 'Albatross', 'Cat', 'Alpaca', 'Ape', 'Anaconda'];

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, animals[i], animals[i].indexOf('A'))
}
```